# R Association Rule with loop

Tags: r

I have a customer report including customer ID which repeat many times in each row.
I want to generate An Association Rule report for each customer ID. If there are only a few IDs, I can write down like rhs=c(“ID=465”, “ID=223”). But how about many ID cases?
The following is my try but did now work.
Appreciate your help.
DL

```
uniqID <- unique(Customer$ID)

for (i in 1:length(uniqID)){
  apriori(Customer, 
          parameter=list(minlen=2,supp=0.005,conf=0.8),
          appearance=list(rhs=c("ID=uniqID"), default="lhs"),
          control=list(verbose=F)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
uniqID <- unique(Customer$ID)
uniqID <- paste("ID=", uniqID, sep="")

apriori(Customer, 
        parameter=list(minlen=2,supp=0.005,conf=0.8),
        appearance=list(rhs=uniqID, default="lhs"),
        control=list(verbose=F)
       )
```

Comment: Matt, thank you so much. you save me a day work. have a good day.

Comment: @user6106408 If the answer helped, you should check it and mark the question as solved.